# Retrieving Data From Fire-base Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

one problem I am facing

can I take DataSnapshot more then one in Firebase database. My application is stopping when I am considering 4 DataSnapshot .

I am really interested in knowing some facts about how to retrieve data from the fire-base database and then how to use it.

1. How the fire-base is saving the data when we write

   ```
   mRef = new Firebase("https://fireapp-83sff9.firebio.com")
   ```

   for example.
2. can it be saved in a list or in array ? if yes how? please give a simple example for understanding it better.

Answer (score 1):

1. Firebase database is like a NoSql database. The database is a huge
   JSON object where data are stored in key-value pair.
2. Yes we can save array data to firebase, by passing array to set() method of firebase.

Like

```
firebase.database().ref('something').set(['one','two','three','four'])
```

It will be saved like

```
root
   |-- something
        |-- 0: one
        |-- 1: two
        |-- 2: three
        |-- 3: four
```

I suggest you to go through this [link](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html)  as well as firebase-database's Docs.